# Not displaying image jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I've been trying to make an image appear, but nothing happens. I've looked up various methods and applied them, yet I haven't been able to achieve it. I'm starting to think that maybe I'm placing in the wrong file. In applets, I only need to place the image in the build folder. As for `JFrame`, I'm not sure where. I tried placing it in build, no image. I tried placing it in `src`, still nothing. Below is a bit of what I've been testing so far. Maybe it's the image location or the code.

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Changey extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JPanel panel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
//JLabel label = new JLabel();

public Changey() {
    initComponents();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Cookie.png");
    //JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    //panel.add(label);

    //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cookie.png"));

    //Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Cookie.png");
    //JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
    //frame.add(label);

    //label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Cookie.png"));
    //panel.add(label);

    //JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Cookie.png"));
    //img.setBounds(200, 300, 100, 100); // x, y, width, height
    //panel.add(img);

    //ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Cookie.png");
    //label.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
    //panel.add(label);
    //image.getImage();

    //label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Cookie.PNG"));
    //label.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
    //panel.add(label);

    setSize(1130,380);
    setTitle("Image");        
}
```

Comment: 1) Why the bunch of commented out code? For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) that tries to load a single image. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) Application resources ..

Comment: .. will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

After the ImageIcon() constructor you can call `image.getImageLoadStatus()` to see how the loading went.

To check if the code can see a file, use 
    `File myFile = new File("Cookie.png");
    System.out.println(myFile.exists());`

If you use the file as a resource, it should be in the classpath.

If you use the file with a relative path, it should be relative to the application's start folder.